# Cleaning up a database in django before every test method

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models

By default when Django runs against sqlite backend it creates a new in memory database for a test. That means for every class that derives from unittest.TestCase, I get a new database. Can this be changed so that it is cleared before every test method is run?

Example: I am testing a manager class that provides additional abstraction on top of Django persistent objects. The code looks more-less like that

```
class TestForManager(unittest.TestCase):
  def testAddingBlah(self):
    manager = Manager()
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 0)
    manager.addBlah(...)
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 1)

  def testAddingBlahInDifferentWay(self):
    manager = Manager()
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 0)
    manager.addBlahInDifferentWay(...)
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 1)
```

Now, the first assertion of second test fails, because the state of the database is preserved between test calls and there already is an instance of `Blah` in the database.

Comment: What version of django do you use? Because all current versions flush database on every test method call.

Comment: 0.96. Maybe it's worth upgrading then. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `django.test.TestCase` not `unittest.TestCase`. And it works in all major versions of Django!

Comment: From my experience, this only cleans up the default database and your on your own to clean up any other databases.  Whats the best way to clean up non-default databases?

Comment: Seriously, this post just saved me an hour of messing around. Thank you.

Comment: Set `multi_db=True` to clean all databases (in case you're using more than one)

Comment: Never say "as always" - you're asking for trouble. :-)

Comment: Thanks, it was `unittest.TestCase` added by PyCharm. Works now with `django.test.TestCase`!

Comment: Just to confirm, and provide a recent date, that this answer solved my issue too

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tearDown` method. It will be called after your test is run. You can delete all Blahs there.

Comment: also notice that you can use ``setUp`` to set up the database before running the testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Make them in two different functions both are not test function. Finally call the dependent functions from one test function.

Comment: Could you add some short sample that gives better insight into what you mean?

Comment: Please visit here for details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866805/django-rest-framework-unit-testing-database-issue/54809606#54809606

Comment: I'm sorry I meant you could improve your answer by linking and example. In other words your answer seems uncomplete to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the following?  This accomplishes what you need without a significant change to your code.

```
class TestOneForManager(unittest.TestCase):
  def testAddingBlah(self):
    manager = Manager()
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 0)
    manager.addBlah(...)
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 1)

class TestTwoForManager(unittest.TestCase):
  def testAddingBlahInDifferentWay(self):
    manager = Manager()
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 0)
    manager.addBlahInDifferentWay(...)
    self.assertEquals(manager.getBlahs(), 1)
```

---

**Edit**.  The "reset on TestCase" feature gives you complete control.

- Many test methods in a single TestCase are good when you have test cases that don't interfere with each other.
- Few test methods in a single TestCase are good when you have test cases that interfere with each other.

You can choose which model applies to your tests by grouping your test methods in one or many TestCases.  You have total and complete control.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I could do that. But it kinda looks weird. It seems good to keep tests for a single class under one unittest.TestCase. I was more looking for some solution that would tune Django to do the right thing.

Comment: "It seems good to keep tests for a single class under one unittest.TestCase"  There's no compelling reason for this.  The original unittest design had a single runTest method.  One test per Case is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For clearing non-default databases, add `multi_db = True` in the class

eg

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase)
    multi_db = True

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```