# Override Django cache settings in tests

Tags: python, django, caching, testing, django-settings

I'm using [`Django DummyCache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development) in my tests, however, there are a few tests which relay on real caching so using fake caching is not good here.

Is there a clean way to override the general [`Django settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#caches) for a certain module or scope? Preferably using a [`Python decorator`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

I'm using `Django` version `1.8.4`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings
You can use decorator `override_settings`

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(CACHES=...)
    def test_something(self):
        ....
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to override a setting. From [Django documentation: Testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#overriding-settings):

> For testing purposes it’s often useful to change a setting temporarily and revert to the original value after running the testing code. For this use case Django provides a standard Python context manager ... `settings()`, which can be used like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        # Override the LOGIN_URL setting
        with self.settings(CACHES={'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'}}):
            response = self.client.get(...)
```

I have tested the above approach with several other settings myself, but not with the particular cache setting, but this is the general idea.

EDIT (credits @Alasdair):

Regrading the particular setting override, the following warning can be found in the documentation:

> Altering the `CACHES`setting is possible, but a bit tricky if you are using internals that make using of caching, like `django.contrib.sessions`. For example, you will have to reinitialize the session backend in a test that uses cached sessions and overrides `CACHES`.

Comment: Overriding the `CACHES` setting should work most of the time, but you can run into problems sometimes. There's [a warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.modify_settings) in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pytest, you could put this fixture in your **conftest.py** file

```
from django.core.cache import cache

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def reset_cache():
    """
    Fixture to reset the cache after each test
    """
    yield
    cache.clear()
```