# Django tests failing when run with all test cases

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with tests. When I run some tests I launch separately, they pass. When all together then fail.

```
@mock.patch(
    'apps.abstract.validators.years_range_is_not_future', new=fake_years_range_is_not_future
)
def test_create_building_with_validation_of_foundation_period(self):

self.c.login(username=self.user.username, password='111')

response = self.c.post(
    '/en/api/buildings/',
    data={
        'name': "New Building",
        'foundation_period': {
            'lower': MIN_INT_VALUE,
            'upper': MAX_INT_VALUE
        },
        'stream': {
            'uuid': s_uuid(self.stream)
        }
    }
)

self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I read about this problem here
[why would a django test fail only when the full test suite is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792439/why-would-a-django-test-fail-only-when-the-full-test-suite-is-run) 
and tried to patch the validator in the serializer file as shown here

```
@mock.patch(
    'apps.buildings.api.serializers.years_range_is_not_future', new=fake_years_range_is_not_future
)
def test_create_building_with_validation_of_foundation_period(self):
..............................................................
```

but then I get an incomprehensible for me  exception

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1049, in _dot_lookup
    return getattr(thing, comp)
AttributeError: module 'apps.buildings.api' has no attribute 'serializers'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1149, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1205, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1375, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1062, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1051, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
  File "/home/env/project/apps/buildings/api/serializers.py", line 12, in <module>
    from apps.communities.api.serializers import CommunityBriefSerializer
  File "/home/env/project/apps/communities/api/serializers.py", line 297, in <module>
    class CommunityOfficialRequestBuildingSerializer(BaseCommunityOfficialRequestSerializer):
  File "/home/rp/env/project/apps/communities/api/serializers.py", line 299, in CommunityOfficialRequestBuildingSerializer
    from apps.buildings.api.serializers import BuildingBriefSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name 'BuildingBriefSerializer'
```

help please understand what I'm doing wrong

project structure (`__init__.py` files not listed)

```
project
       |__apps
             |__communities
             |             |_api
             |                  |_serializers.py
             |
             |__buildings
             |           |_api
             |           |    |_serializers.py
             |           |
             |           |_tests
             |                  |_test.py
             | 
             |_abstract
                      |_validators.py
```

Comment: Is there a `/apps/communities/api/serializers.py` missing? Are there any `__init__.py` files?

Comment: __init__.py file is in folders buildings and api..../apps/communities/api/serializers.py exist and __init__.py file is in communities and  communities/api/....

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rp/env/project/apps/communities/api/serializers.py", line 299, in CommunityOfficialRequestBuildingSerializer
    from apps.buildings.api.serializers import BuildingBriefSerializer
```

suggests that your import statement is inside a `class` or a `def` or some other statement.

Maybe the import statement is executed after you mocked `apps.buildings.api.serializers`. If you move this import to the top of the file, then `BuildingBriefSerializer` will probably become available before `apps.buildings.api.serializers` is mocked, and your tests will pass.
This would also explain why the tests run, when you run them individually.

Comment: this import should be in that class to avoid cyclic imports...I walked this exclusion via new_callable attribute in patch but but tests still fail ...